# How to reshape data to None in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm using tensorflow run queues to feed my data during training time:

```
X, Y = tf.train.batch(
           [image, label], 
           batch_size=64 
       )
```

However X, Y have forced shape of [64, 32, 32,3], and [64, 10]. During evaluation time I'd like to run loss operation on whole test set, which has dimensions: [10000, 32, 32, 3] and [10000, 10]. I would use feed_dict property in session.run() to overwrite X,Y with my values, however they have incompatible shapes.

Can I somehow instruct tensorflow to forget about first dimension, that is reshape [64, 32, 32, 3] -> [None, 32, 32, 3]? Or is there any other option  for me to replace X,Y with another value.

Whole dataset is small enough to fit in memory, therefore I'm using similar approach as in https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r0.9/tensorflow/examples/how_tos/reading_data/fully_connected_preloaded.py

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bit subtle: in TensorFlow terminology, you don't actually want to `reshape` the tensor (i.e. change the number of elements in each dimension), but instead you want TensorFlow to "forget" a specific dimension, in order to feed values with a range of sizes.

The [`tf.placeholder_with_default()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#placeholder_with_default) op is designed to support this case. It takes a default input, which in your case would be the next training batch (of shape `[64, ...]`); and a shape, which in your case would be the same shape as the input, with the first dimension set to `None`. You can then feed this placeholder with values of any batch size.

Here's an example of how you'd use it:

```
X_batch, Y_batch = tf.train.batch([image, label], batch_size=64)

# Alternatively, `X_shape = [None, 32, 32, 3]`
X_shape = tf.TensorShape([None]).concatenate(X_batch.get_shape()[1:])
# Alternatively, `Y_shape = [None, 10]`
Y_shape = tf.TensorShape([None]).concatenate(Y_batch.get_shape()[1:])

# Create tensors that can be fed with a less specific shape
# than `X_batch`, `Y_batch`.
X = tf.placeholder_with_default(X_batch, shape=X_shape)
Y = tf.placeholder_with_default(Y_batch, shape=Y_shape)
```

Comment: This is perfect, just what I'm looking for! One additional question though.

When I use feed_dict, can I use device placement CPU for memory allocation since whole dict cannot fit onto GPU? Will most of my computation run on GPU then or not?